# sshfs:type of file differs from mountpoint

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, sshfs, fuse

```
sshfs --version
SSHFS version 2.8
FUSE library version: 2.5.0
fusermount version: 2.5.0
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.5
```

I am trying to mount remote windows filesystem folder to linux server. I have installed openSSH on windows pc and  sshfs  on my linux server.

```
sshfs  test@10.199.62.156:/cygdrive/d/test     /mnt/
```

error comes as:

```
test@10.199.62.156:/cygdrive/d/test: type of file differs from mountpoint
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Does `D:\test` exist, and if so is it file or folder?

Comment: Why use `sshfs` when an SMB fileshare would give you more efficient and more accurate filesystem behaviour?

Comment: D:\test is a folder in windows, SMB protocol is blocked due to recent ransomware virus.

Comment: Even i created one xml file inside test folder, then also getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

on one side you are pointing to a **file**: /cygdrive/d/test

on the other, to a **folder**: /mnt/

Solution:

- sync the folder /mnt to the folder /cygdrive/d
- sync directly a file from /mnt to the file /cygdrive/d/test